# Sublist creation, splitting and joining

Tags: list-manipulation, string-manipulation

I have a not very usefully-formatted string list and I would like to create certain sublists from it.

```
lis = {"F","aa","b","12","c","d","e","2","T","n","1","m","o","3","F","r","s","23","q","0"}
```

The desired sublists are to end up containing 5 elements: the flag ("F"), a string produced by joining adjacent alpha elements (if any to join), then a string representation of a number, then another string produced by joining adjacent alpha elements (if any to join), and lastly another string representation of a number.  Perhaps easier to visualize as:

```
res = {{"F","aab","12","cde","2"},{"F","rs","23","q","0"}}
```

Thanks as always for ideas!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
rule = {"F", 
    a___?(StringMatchQ[LetterCharacter ..]), 
    b_?(StringMatchQ[NumberString]), 
    c___?(StringMatchQ[LetterCharacter ..]), 
    d_?(StringMatchQ[NumberString])} :> 
 {"F", StringJoin[a], b, StringJoin[c], d};

SequenceCases[lis, rule]
```

> ```
> {{"F", "aab", "12", "cde", "2"}, {"F", "rs", "23", "q", "0"}}
> ```

Answer (score 2):

```
la = 
 {"F", "aa", "b", "12", "c", "d", "e", "2", 
  "T", "n", "1", "m", "o", "3", 
  "F", "r", "s", "23", "q", "0"};
```

Step 1

```
lb = SequenceCases[SplitBy[la, UpperCaseQ], x : {{"F"}, _} :> Join @@ x]
```

{{"F", "aa", "b", "12", "c", "d", "e", "2"}, {"F", "r", "s", "23",
"q", "0"}}

Step 2

```
With[{lc = StringMatchQ[LetterCharacter ..]},
  lb /. {"F", a__?lc, n1_, b__?lc, n2_} :> 
    {"F", StringJoin[a], n1, StringJoin[b], n2}]
```

{{"F", "aab", "12", "cde", "2"}, {"F", "rs", "23", "q", "0"}}

Answer (score 1):

```
Clear["Global`*"];

lis = {"F", "aa", "b", "12", "c", "d", "e", "2", "T", "n", "1", "m", 
   "o", "3", "F", "r", "s", "23", "q", "0"};

SequenceCases[lis, {"F"
   , p__?(StringFreeQ[NumberString])
   , q_?(StringMatchQ[NumberString])
   , r__?(StringFreeQ[NumberString])
   , s_?(StringMatchQ[NumberString])
   } :> {"F", StringJoin@p, q, StringJoin@r, s}
 ]

SequenceReplace[#, {"F"
     , p__?(StringFreeQ[NumberString])
     , q_?(StringMatchQ[NumberString])
     , r__?(StringFreeQ[NumberString])
     , s_?(StringMatchQ[NumberString])
     , x___
     } :> Sequence @@ {"F", StringJoin@p, q, StringJoin@r, s}
   ] & /@ Split[lis, #2 =!= "F" &]
```

---

> {{"F", "aab", "12", "cde", "2"}, {"F", "rs", "23", "q", "0"}}

Answer (score 1):

```
lis = {"F", "aa", "b", "12", "c",
       "d", "e", "2", "T", "n",
       "1", "m", "o", "3", "F",
       "r", "s", "23", "q", "0"};
```

---

Using `SequenceSplit` and `Cases`:

```
rule = {"F", a__?LetterQ,
         b_?DigitQ,
         c__?LetterQ,
         d_?DigitQ} :> {"F", "" <> a, b, "" <> c, d};

Cases[SequenceSplit[lis, rule], strl_ /; MatchQ[strl, {"F", __}]]

(*{{"F", "aab", "12", "cde", "2"}, {"F", "rs", "23", "q", "0"}}*)
```